# HBase Hive handler is not working

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

Hi i am planning to integrate **HBase** and **HIVE** for one of my project .
I am confused in adding jars and where to add these jars?
I am using **Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.7.0** .

I have downloaded jars:

```
guava-r09.jar
hbase-0.92.0.jar
hive-hbase-handler-0.9.0.jar
zookeeper-3.3.4.jar
```

I ran this command to create table

```
CREATE TABLE hbase_table_emp(id int, name string, role string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:name,cf1:role")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "emp");
```

Now where should I copy all this jars?
Do i have to copy in /usr/lib/hive location and then i have to run add jar command?
All this jar version will work for my Hadoop version ?
I have just copied jars in one of the directory and then providing path to directory in hive, I am running `add jars` command, but it throws error:

```
    FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a host:port pair: PBUF

quickstart.cloudera���ʼ��+��
```

Answer (score 0):

If you place jars in /lib directory then all jars automatically available in hive CLASSPATH and you don't need add those jars explicitly again using `add jar` command.

The error you getting because `add jar` command expect fully qualified path of a jar.

```
add jar <fully qualified path of jar>;
```

Read [hive-hbase](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration) handler for more details.

Comment: /lib of hadoop directory or /lib of hive directory .

Comment: i am adding it like add jar  /home/cloudera/jars/hbase-0.92.0.jar;

Comment: only hive-hbase-handler-0.9.0.jar should be enough to connect hive to hbase.

Comment: Ok but do i have to copy my downloaded jars in the /usr/lib/hive/lib .Right now i have kept it in the jars directory .

Comment: try first with hive-hbase-handler-0.9.0.jar if you get any exception then add required jars to CLASSPATH.

Comment: I am getting this error /usr/lib/hive/lib/hbase-0.92.0.jar (No such file or directory) but this not the HBase version i am using